# Is there any good text introducing a part of Borel-hierarchy which is in need in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, reference-request, book-recommendation, borel-sets

Is there any good text introducing a subpart of Borel-hierarchy which is in need in measure theory, which can be done in short time? Say, 1~3 days if possible. (Assuming I'm studying about 14hours a day)

To be more precise, I want to learn that "The Sigma-algebra generated by a set $S$" is exactly $\bigcup_{\alpha<\omega_1} \prod_{\alpha}^0$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foran's book and Goffman's book are especially good for what you want, while Bruckner/Bruckner/Thomson's book, Natanson's book, Cohn's book, Billingsley's book, and Vestrup's book all have more than the average amount (for a real analysis text) on Borel sets. Hrbacek/Jech's book and Devlin's book both have relatively elementary treatments of the hierarchy result. Finally, there's a chapter in Laczkovich's book on Borel sets that is very good for an initial encounter with them.

[**Fundamentals of Real Analysis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824784537) by James Foran

[**Real Functions**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1124060154) by Casper Goffman

[**Real Analysis**] by Bruckner/Bruckner/Thomson (google for a freely available digital copy)

[**Theory of Functions of a Real Variable**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0019CL610) (Volume 2) by Isidor P. Natanson

[**Measure Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817630031) by Donald L. Cohn

[**Probability and Measure**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118122372) by Patrick Billingsley

[**The Theory of Measures and Integration**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471249777) by Eric M. Vestrup

[**Introduction to Set Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824779150) by Hrbacek/Jech

[**The Joy of Sets. Fundamentals of Contemporary Set Theory**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387940944) by Keith Devlin

[**Conjecture and Proof**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883857227) by Miklós Laczkovich

*(ADDED NEXT DAY)* I don't know how I forgot about Rooij/Schikhof's book below. I rank it with Foran's and Goffman's book as real analysis texts that I think would be most useful for what you want:

[**A Second Course on Real Functions**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521283612) by A. C. M. van Rooij and W. H. Schikhof

Comment: Have a look at Fremlins five-volume opus on measure theory:  https://www.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm       It has about **everything**.