# Gentle Introduction to Descriptive Set theory

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, descriptive-set-theory

If find the common literature on Descriptive Set theory pretty tough.
Is there a gentle recommandation? I would really like to learn this topic on my own, so I am searching for something diguestible where the exercises are not as tough, to make progress and get the ability to read more advanced literature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Classical Descriptive Set Theory"
by
Alexander S. Kechris

Comment: You consider this gentle? Most of the Proofs are more or less scetches, and the easiest exercises in the book are the toughest on a homework sheet.

Comment: Yes it is gentle. In addition, the author is one of the best in this area of math which is a big plus.

Comment: I disagree with you. It is a good book, but very dense, and the exercises are pretty hard.

Comment: A bit more basic and accessible, especially regarding background in other mathematical fields, is [**A Course on Borel Sets**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0387984127) by Sashi Mohan Srivastava (1998) and [**Set Theory. With an Introduction to Descriptive Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0720404703) by Kuratowski/Mostowski (2nd edition, 1978). A lot more basic, but also of possible interest, is [**Set Theory**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1461488532) by Abhijit Dasgupta (2014). **(continued)**

Comment: For basics about the Borel set hierarchy and Baire function hierarchy from a real analysis perspective, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/683897/13130) and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4172091/13130).

Comment: While I agree with the comments above that Kechris is the best book to learn DST from, there are some lecture notes by Anush Tserunyan that are based on (parts of) Kechris and are very good. They are freely available on her website, together with some exercises to go with them https://www.math.mcgill.ca/atserunyan/lecture_notes.html

Answer (score 4):

I like Chapter 8 in

*Cohn, Donald L.*, Measure theory., Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. ix, 373 p. (1993). [ZBL0860.28001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0860.28001).

Intended as a first course in measure theory, aimed at a student with no special knowledge of (logic, foundations, set theory).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the recommandation. I will take a look at it.