# How do we prove that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra cannot be constructed from the open sets using only countably many layers of construction?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory

Let $X_0$ be the set of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Define
$X_{n+1}$ to be the set comprised of element of $X_n$ and their complement and countable unions. Then I cannot prove that
$\bigcup_{n\in \omega} X_n$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. I need to define $X_\alpha$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ and then take the union to be able to prove that the result is a $\sigma$-algebra.

However, I don't know how to prove that $\bigcup_{n\in \omega} X_n$ is strictly smaller than the Borel $\sigma$-algebra either. An argument involving cardinality won't work here. Could you give me a hint or a reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the references in my answers to [Is there any good text introducing a part of Borel-hierarchy which is in need in measure theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/683897/13130) and [Constructing sigma algebras in countably many steps](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3075888/13130), along with other answers/comments there as well as the same in the *Linked* and *Related* questions listed on the right side of those question/answer pages.

Comment: @DánielG. Is there a more accessible answer?

Comment: The only proof I know of is the one in the book of Kechris (the second answer in the linked question) which uses "universal sets". Maybe some of the examples in the answer linked by @Dave L. Renfro are more elementary.